# DetailViewController initializer issue

Tags: swift

I am trying to pass an object through segue, however, I am getting an error in DetailViewController. It says DetailViewController does not have selectedCountry and selectedCity initializer. How could I able to overcome this issue or is there a better way to passing data?

**SelectedCountry.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct SelectedCountry {
  var selectedCountry : Country
  var selectedCity : City
}
```

**MainViewController.swift**

```
let selectedItem = SelectedCountry(
    selectedState: self.stateVM.cityState(atIndex: selectedIndexPath.row), 
    selectedCity: self.cityVM.cityItem(atIndex: selectedIndexPath.row))


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "isCountry" {
          if let selectedItem = sender as? SelectedCountry, let detailViewController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
            detailViewController.selectedState = selectedItem.selectedState
            detailViewController.selectedCity = selectedItem.selectedCity
          }
      }
  }
```

**DetailViewController.swift**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
  // initializatior issue
  var selectedCity : City
  var selectedCountry : Country

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    displayData()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual thing is to make these Optionals:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
  var selectedCity : City?
  var selectedCountry : Country?
```

That solves the initializer issue, because now these properties have an initial value, namely `nil`. You will, however, need to adjust the rest of your code accordingly; but the compiler will guide you so it won't be difficult.